# How to increase connection timeout for Mongolab while connecting from loopback mongodb driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop, mlab

I have hosted my mongodb in mongolab. I have created a ODM in loopback and made a connection to mongolab.
Sometimes the connection gets established but other times due to bad connection it gets timedout. I want to increase this timeout so that it does get connected everytime. I did not find any solution even on Strongloop site.

I tried even adding a query string param in connection string for mongolab:
?connectTimeoutMS=1000000
Even this did not help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `connectionTimeout` setting in your `dataSources.json` file.

```
{
  "YourMongoDB": {
    "name": "YourMongoDB",
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "connectionTimeout": 1000000
  }
}
```